# C# global variables

Tags: c#, global-variables

I'm an HW and PCB designer with some basic C language knowledge.
I have to help a friend with some mods in a c# project used for a custom windows application.
I don't know much about c# or the structure of files and project in visual studio 2022.
There are some .cs files and a MainWindow.xaml.cs.

In the mainwindow.xaml.cs file in this part of the code I want to set a generic variable CHK to 1

```
private void Debug_ck_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (Debug_ck.IsChecked == true)
     {
          CHK = 1;
          string text = string.Format("CMD5\0");
          com.Write(text);
          Start.IsEnabled = false;
          Stop.IsEnabled = true;
          WaveDis.Ena_run(true);
          Calibration.IsEnabled = true;
          Reset.IsEnabled = true;
     }
}
```

Based on the value of this variable I added an If condition in a different .cs file of the project (WaveDis.cs).

```
if (CHK == 0)
{
     FsrLowPass(buff_pos);
     FsrHighPass(buff_pos);
}
                
if (CHK == 1)
{
     FsrDummy(buff_pos);
}
```

I declared this variable in both files so: `public int CHK = 0;`
The program on mainwindow file doesn't seem to change the value of this variable, so only the first If condition is executed. Maybe the value is not updated through the .cs files.
My question is simple, is there a way to do this basic job?

Expecting: Set a variable based upon a flag condition and run some code in different .cs file based on the value of the variable.

Comment: There is a lot to say about this "problem". But in general you really need to understand how C# treats variables. See [the specification first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables) and if you find this too much academic then look around about "static variables" (and remember that littering your program with static variables is never ending well)

Comment: There's no such thing as a "global variable" in C#. The closest is a `public static int CHK` in one of the classes, say `MyClass`, and then use is as `MyClass.CHK` wherever you want. But for good reasons this is not considered good practice.

Answer (score 0):

One of the (IMHO) biggest advantages of C# compared to C (or C++) is it's automatic global scoping of classes. Every class declared in a cs file is automatically visible to all other cs files in the same project (no #include nightmares). If it is declared public it is even visible to all files and projects that reference the declaring project.

You cannot declare variables outside classes in C#, but you can declare them static. A variable declared `public static` is therefore visible from everywhere.

So you can declare your variable in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` as `public static int CHK` and access it as `MainWindow.CHK` from everywhere within the project. *However* that is considered rather bad style for an OO language such as C# and you should really think about whether you can instead provide the variable as parameter somewhere to the method in the `WaveDis` class.